# how to add the overflow menu inside the fragment in android

Tags: android, menu

I am trying to make menu visible in the action bar even in the devices which have hardware menu button available  but how to overflow the menu in the fragments in android. 
I am getting error in .get method of this 
in this line

```
ViewConfiguration.get(frag);
```

this is inside my fragment

```
 private void showOverflowMenu(Fragment frag) {
    try {
        ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(frag);
        Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("menu_item1");
        if (menuKeyField != null) {
            menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
            menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

this is my  onCreateOptionsMenu. It is working fine in devices with the hardware menu button but i want to display it in the action bar but i am getting error in .get method.

```
 public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // Do something that differs the Activity's menu here
    // menu.clear();
     inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
  }
```

this is my menu.xml

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_1"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="always|withText"
    android:title="@string/menu_item1"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_2"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:showAsAction="always|withText"
    android:title="@string/menu_item2"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_3"
    android:orderInCategory="3"
    android:showAsAction="always|withText"
    android:title="@string/menu_item3"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by changing the

```
android:showAsAction="always|withText"
```

with

```
android:showAsAction="never"
```

in this way the menu appears as a overflow menu and their is no need for
showOverflowMenu() etc.